# Discord js How I can search for userID in json file using for...in

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

The problem I have is when I use this loop, I only get the guild id, but I need to get the user id.
My Code:

```
for(let userID in money){
    res.push({"guildid": message.guild.id, "id": userID, "money": money[message.guild.id][userID].money })
    res.sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[1] - Object.values(a)[1])
    console.log(userID);
}
```

My JSON file:

```
{
"2543634674355 <======GuildID":
    {"309781817504956426 <======userID":
     {       "name":"user1#7777",
             "money":15000},
     "868630066064654397 <======userID":
{            "name":"user2#7777",
             "money":0}},
"402469770760421406 <======GuildID":
{    "309781817504956426 <======userID":
{            "name":"user1#7777",
             "money":0
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
for (let userID in money[message.guild.id]) {
  // Your code
}
```

Very basic javascript, very basic logic. Just go through the logic: you want to loop through all of the user ID data in the current guild, contained in the JSON file (assuming the `money` variable contains the JSON data). So get the current guild data from the JSON data (`money[message.guild.id]`), and then loop through the user IDs in it with the `for/in` loop.

Nothing to it. You may want to go through some Javascript tutorials and get more acquainted with Javascript while/before diving into discord bot programming, so you can better understand how to code this type of logic.